# Created docker image for spring boot app, not accessible

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I have created a docker image for my spring boot app "payalbnsl/shoppingapp"

First i start the container for mongodb: "docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mongodb --network n1  -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongodb -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mongodb -e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=levent -e MONGO_USERNAME=mongodb  -e MONGO_PASSWORD=mongodb mongo --auth"

Then i run the image : "docker run -d --network n1 -p 9000:9000 payalbnsl/shoppingapp:1"

When i try to access the url "http://13.233.154.209:9000", it redirects to "http://13.233.154.209:9000/products", like it should as coded. But i keep getting 404 error. No page is displayed.

Logs are exactly same both when running locally and on ec2 using docker

[image]

But locally i can see the web page
[image]
While running on ec2, i get this page:
[image]
Though i just entered http://13.233.154.209:9000, it redirects to http://13.233.154.209:9000/products on production, but i don't see any web page.

I have opened up port 9000 for ec2 instance.
[image]

Why there is 404, i cannot understand. I am using JSP for frontend.

Application has successfully connected to mongo. Both are on bridge network n1. I have enabled firewall on this port. Even if i run this application locally using docker it gives same 404. On any instance, i am getting 404.

**Also for me "curl -i --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/containers/json " works while "curl -i --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://containers/json " gives 404. Not sure what it means exactly.**

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks,
Payal

Comment: I'd look into your application and why it returns 404 when you don't expect it. Check its logs and code and consider extending your answer with those.

Comment: Updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

It was a spring boot jsp problem. I had placed jsps in the webapp folder and when i created an executable jar file, jsps were not copied. Hence created a war file and redeployed. It worked. Resolved!

Comment: Better really describe what solved it, than it makes your question have some value.